# Sometimes Losing Byte When Using Pexpect and Pyserial

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial, pexpect

I've been using Pexpect and Pyserial together and usually it works fine, but occasionally I lose a byte. What I'm trying to do is receive a string of hex bytes where the first few bytes are always the same, but the bytes after that are different, and then I want to print the different bytes. A simplified example of what I'm doing is:

('\x00\x01\x02\xab\xcd\xef\xff') is sent where ff is a flag signalling the 
end of the signal)

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')
ds = fdpexpect.fdspawn(ser)

ds.expect('\x00\x01\x02')
data = ser.read(1)
print(data)
```

The issue I'm running into is data is sometimes \xab while other times the \xab byte is somehow lost and instead it is \xcd. I'm running on a raspberry pi using Ubunut MATE 16.04.02 if that makes any difference.